# UITableView loading and reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, feed

I have trouble loading a UITableView with multiple sections. In order to fill it I use a function (fetches feed from Twitter). At the moment the view loads, the function returns NULL values for it's fields, but after a few seconds it returns the desired feed.

However, before the desired feed is returned, the fields in my tableView are shown to be NULL and then they refresh and are filled properly (No NULL values).

My question is, How can I make the tableView cells not load until the feed is properly loaded?

I have the same problem with my Facebook feed, however it crashes because it doesn't even return any of the values.

in ViewDidLoad I have put

```
[self getTwitterFeed:^() { 

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

EDIT here is the code of the method

```
- (void)getTwitterFeed:(void (^)(void))completion {
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account
                              accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
@try
{
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TwitterLoggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {

        [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                         options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if (granted == YES)
             {
                 NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                             accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                 if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
                 {
                     ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"TwitterAccountNumber" ]];

                     NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];

                     NSMutableDictionary *parameters =
                     [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                     [parameters setObject:@"35" forKey:@"count"];
                     [parameters setObject:@"true" forKey:@"include_entities"];


                     SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest
                                               requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                               requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                               URL:requestURL parameters:parameters];

                     postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

                     [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:
                      ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse
                        *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                      {
                          self.dataSource = [NSJSONSerialization
                                             JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                             error:&error];

                          if (self.dataSource.count != 0) {
                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                  NSLog(@"Description %@",_dataSource);
                                  for(int i=0;i<[_dataSource count];i++)
                                  {
                                      NSMutableString *url = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"https://www.twitter.com/%@/status/%@",[[[_dataSource objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"screen_name"],[[_dataSource objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"id"]];

                                      [tweetURL addObject:url];

                                      NSMutableString *urlApp = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"twitter://user?screen_name=%@?status?id=%@",[[[_dataSource objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"screen_name"],[[_dataSource objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"id"]];

                                      [tweetAppURL addObject:urlApp];
                                  }

                                  CGRect frame = CGRectMake (120, 120, 80, 80);
                                  activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
                                  activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
                                  activityIndicator.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
                                  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                                  activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
                                  [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];



                             completion();

                                  //[self.tableView reloadData];
                              });

                          }
                      }];
                 }
             } else {

             }  

         }];
    }


    else  //IF FEED IS NOT TURNED ON
    {

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your TWITTER feed is either turned of or isn't initiated!" message:@"Please enable it in Settings" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

         }

@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
```

}

Comment: set total rows is 0 to until the feed will load

Comment: How and where should I set that? In the numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: Exactly, return 0 if you have no feed data

Comment: add your code for reference

Comment: I pasted the code above.I know my code is a bit messy, but I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do something perhaps

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self getTwitterFeed:^() { // Completion block
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           [myTableView reloadData];
                       });
    }];
}


- (void)getTwitterFeed:(void (^)(void))completion {
    // Get the feed and call:
    NSLog(@"We finished receiving the data");
    completion();
}
```

And to show the correct number of rows (need to be edited according to # sections)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (self.myFeedArray.count == 0 ? 0 : self.myFeedArray.count);
}
```

Loading cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(myFeedArray.count == 0) { // no feeds yet
        NSLog(@"The count in the table is 0");
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Updating...";
        [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [cell.textLabel setAlpha:0.5];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        return cell;
    }

    //else do stuff

}
```

Comment: I tried this example but I guess I'm missing something, please check above, I edited my question and pasted my code.

Comment: At first glance I cannot see anything really wrong with your code. See my edited answer and see for yourself if the NSLog - is printed. Also, just to be safe, the table reloading is performed on the main thread.

Comment: I tried printing the values in the cellForRowAtIndex, and it is getting called before this method. So i get Null values and after that I receive the "Finished receiving the data" and the correct values.

Comment: Isn't that the way it is suppose to be? When you set the delegate/datasoure of your table view the cellForRowAtIndex will be called among other protocol functions. When the fetch completes you will update the tableview with the desired data.

Comment: Well yes I understand that, but I don't understand how to make the TableViewCells not load until the feed is full. What should I do to avoid reloading it twice?

Comment: The reason I need to find that out is because this is my twitter feed.  I returns values, but they are NULL (strings). While If I try doing this with my facebook feed, it returns Null value for the whole feed and it crashes.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you for your help. Live long and prosper! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLForPayload]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchCompleted:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
   });
}



-(void) fetchCompleted:(NSData *)responseData
 {


   // Complete data available now reload TableView

 }
```